# logoff user with .cmd file on destop

Tags: cmd

I have a code :

```
@echo off
rem :: Get session ID
for /f "tokens=3" %%I in ('qwinsta /server:10.10.100.1 ^| find /i " %username% "') do (set _ID=%%I)
rem :: Logoff user
logoff %_ID% /server:10.10.100.1
```

It works if I type it into command line, but when I take this code and make .cmd file and put on my desktop nothing happends. Don't know why when It works. I also tried put (ping localhost -n 1 -w 5000) to give time to set _ID variable, but didn't help. What could be a problem? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and look at the last line for an error.

```
@echo off
rem :: Get session ID
for /f "tokens=3" %%I in ('qwinsta /server:10.10.100.1 ^| find /i " %username% "') do (set _ID=%%I)
rem :: Logoff user
echo logoff %_ID% /server:10.10.100.1
pause
```

Comment: No error. It worked this morning for 3 times, then again it stopped. I saw that the same code stucked in loop and after that it closed the remote desktop window, but it did not log off user. Nothing changed in code, lol.